# Which security protocol do you use in OAuth if starting at Google?

Tags: security, redirect, oauth, openid, saml

Say you have a website www.site.come and you click 'Log in with Google', the google log in page shows up, you sign in and then directed back to www.site.com but now logged in as the proper user.

What protocol would you use if you started at Google? So for instance you start at google.com, log directly into google and as a logged in user, there exists a button which goes to www.site.com which when you click it will bring you to the www.site.com but signed in based on some information that is passed when the button is clicked. Would this be equivalent to SAML? Or more to OpenId?

Answer (score 0):

It's OAuth 2.0. You can test it with https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

Comment: Mmm but even in oauth 2 you start at www.site.com then click a button to say login to google. In my Scenario you start at google logged in and say access this site with the linked account for this google user. Imagine you're at www.site.com and click find my password, type in your email, you go to your email and click the reset password link. The situation of starting at google is like starting at logging into the email, and then clicking that link automatically knows you are the user requesting the login.